# Simple java regex match and replace

Tags: java, regex

So I have `myString` which contains the string

```
"border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;width:8px;background:#bc0b43;float:left;height:12px"
```

I want to use regex to check that it contains `"width:8px" (\bwidth\s*:\s*(\d+)px)`

If true, add the width value (i.e. 8 for above example) to my myList.

Attempt:

```
if (myString.contains("\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)px")) {
    myList.add(valueofwidth) //unsure how to select the width value using regex
}
```

Any help?

EDIT: So I've looked into `contains` method and found that it doesn't allow regex. `matches` will allow regex but it looks for a complete match instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method for that.

From the documentation: -

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.

And then you can get the captured group out of it: -

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)px").matcher(myString);

if (matcher.find()) {
    myList.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me more about `matcher.group(1)`? I believe they're called capture groups?

Comment: You don't *need* to use `matcher.find()`. You *can* use it if you like writing verbose code though.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `(\\d+)` is called capture group. Captured groups are numbered in the order of opening brackets. So, since `(\\d+)` has the first opening brackets, so it is first capture group. And to get the value captured in a group you use `Matcher#group` method, with the group number as parameter.

Comment: You can also see the documentation for more details.

Comment: @Bohemian.. Why do you think, that we don't need `find()` here. This seems to be a valid candidate for it. Since, we need to find a certain pattern in the string, and get it's actual value, so, it is absolutely perfect to use `Matcher.find()`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a Matcher and matcher.find():

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*(?<width>\\d+)px)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(args);
while (matcher.find()) {
    myList.add(matcher.group("width");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that `contains()` doesn't accept a regex, it accepts a literal String.
`matches()` on the other hand *does* accept a regex parameter, but must match the *entire* string to return true.

Next, once you have your match, you can use `replaceAll()` to extract your target content:

```
if (myString.matches(".*\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*\\d+px.*")) {
    myList.add(myString.replaceAll(".*\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)px.*", "$1"))
}
```

This replaces the entire input String with the contents of group #1, which your original regex captures.

Note that I removed the redundant brackets from your original matching regex, but left them in for the replace to capture the target content.