# Escaping set of character by using a single regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of characters: `|`, `#`, `\`that are considered as "reserved" and all occurrences must be escaped. How can I do that **using a single** regex ?

This needs to be done using a single regex, because running a `replaceAll()` for each of the characters in the reserved set greatly reduces the performance.

For instance `escape(I | have \ a dog #)` should yield the result "I \| have \\ a dog \#".

### Solution

Following @neuhaus answer: The regex is `([\\|#])` and the replacement is `\\$0`

Comment: Why are you having to escape them? as for URLs and other forms of data transfer etc you can call encode/decode methods provided for doing just what you are trying to do. ie https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Because this characters are "reserved" and must be escaped when encountered in the input message. It's not about URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a regexp that matches the characters you want.

Example: `/([|#\\])/`

Replace them with the escape character followed by the matched character.

Comment: Can this be done entirely from within the regex ? How can I reference the matched character from within the regex ?

Comment: yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040037/simple-java-regex-match-and-replace

Comment: What is boing done with the regular expression exactly? Why have you tagged your question with the `java` keyword?

Comment: Escaping characters from log lines to prevent log forging attacks: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace